# Update Symfony components

Tags: 8

There are many posts and articles that make vague references to upgrading Symfony 3 to Symfony 4 in Drupal 8. But nothing specific.

For example this one by Ryan Weaver ["Symfony 4 and Drupal"](https://drupalize.me/blog/201802/symfony-4-and-drupal)

I've installed a fresh copy of Drupal 8.8.1 and updated with

```
 composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

Then, I ran

```
composer outdated "symfony/*"
```

Clearly, there are symfony components that are outdated.

[image]

Is it possible to update these "outdated" components? Or, are we stuck till Drupal 9?

Comment: Drupal 8 was successfully updated to Symfony 4, in a massive patch. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2976394#comment-13290353. As you can see the issue is closed now and all further efforts are going into Drupal 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ryan Weaver mentions,

> The current version of Drupal - 8.4 - requires Symfony 3.2.8 or
>   higher, but less than 4.0. In practice, this probably means that your
>   Drupal 8.4 project is using the latest Symfony 3.2.* version. But, you
>   could technically upgrade your Symfony dependencies to version 3.4.
>
> <sub>Source: [Symfony 4 and Drupal](https://drupalize.me/blog/201802/symfony-4-and-drupal)</sub>

Thus, you can, but only for minor versions.

---

To quote Dries Buytaert,

> Our biggest dependency in Drupal 8 is Symfony 3, and according to
>   Symfony's roadmap, Symfony 3 has an end-of-life date in November 2021.
>   This means that after November 2021, security bugs in Symfony 3 will
>   not get fixed. To keep your Drupal sites secure, Drupal must adopt
>   Symfony 4 or Symfony 5 before Symfony 3 goes end-of-life. **A major
>   Symfony upgrade will require us to release Drupal 9** (we don't want to
>   fork Symfony 3 and have to backport Symfony 4 or Symfony 5 bug fixes).
>   This means we have to end-of-life Drupal 8 no later than November
>   2021.
>
> <sub>Source: [Drupal 7, 8 and 9](https://dri.es/drupal-7-8-and-9)</sub>

He says here that Drupal 8 will reach end of life of Nov 2021 because that's Symfonys 3's end of life. Thus, from this, one can conclude that you can't just upgrade D8 to Symfony 4 (another major Symfony version).